# Java Mongo DB aggregation pipeline - $sum will not work while using $unwind?

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am currently working on a mongoDB aggregation pipeline in one of my Java scripts.

The input data can be simplified to a list of orders of different customers. Such as:

| _id | customerId | orderId | shipments | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | a12b4 | shipment1, shipment2 | 30.00 |
| 2 | 456 | a14hf | shipment3 | 40.00 |
| 2 | 123 | a27jd | shipment4 | 20.00 |

_id, customerId, and orderId are strings, the amount a number of type Long, and the shipments are entities of a custom-made class called shipment. Now, I want to aggregate this and show, for every customerId, the total amount of what they spent and all the shipments. Like this for the first customer:

{customerId: 123, shipments: [shipment1, shipment2, shipment4], amount: 50.00}

Data in json format

```js
[
 {
   "_id": 1,
   "customerId": 123,
   "orderId": "a12b4",
   "shipments": ["shipment1","shipment2"],
   "amount": 30
 },
 {
   "_id": 2,
   "customerId": 456,
   "orderId": "a14hf",
   "shipments": ["shipment3"],
   "amount": 40
 },
 {
   "_id": 3,
   "customerId": 123,
   "orderId": "a27jd",
   "shipments": ["shipment4"],
   "amount": 20
 }
]
```

So, I did this:

```
Aggregates.unwind("$shipments"),
Aggregates.group("$customerId",
     Accumulators.sum("amount","$amount"),
     Accumulators.addToSet("shipments", "$shipments")),
Aggregates.out("test_output")
```

And this is where my question comes in:
**Are the usages of unwind and sum exclusive?**

As long as I keep my unwind statement, the sum function does not return the correct result. But it works just fine as soon as I replace shipments by another field that I do not have to unwind.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show your mongo document schema/structure

Comment: data in json are much more useful, because your question is about mongodb

Answer (score 0):

Query

- `unwind` will create many duplicated but you dont need it
- you can `group` and sum, and collect the shipments for each customer
- and then `reduce` to flatten the array, and `union with []` to make it set (not duplicate shipments)

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=62b09f5091b564fc1e7e95b3)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$group": 
   {"_id": "$customerId",
    "shipments": {"$push": "$shipments"},
    "total-amound": {"$sum": "$amount"}}},
 {"$set": 
   {"shipments": 
     {"$setUnion": 
       [{"$reduce": 
           {"input": "$shipments",
            "initialValue": [],
            "in": {"$concatArrays": ["$$value", "$$this"]}}}, []]}}}])
```